# Simplify entity framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a simple linq query, which sort results by a creteria.

```
var vehicles = context.Vehicles
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(v => v.CreatedAt >= DbFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.UtcNow, -10))
    .ToList();
```

But Entity framework transform this simple query to

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (( NOT (([Project1].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (([Project3].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project3].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (([Project2].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project2].[C1] IS NOT NULL)))) THEN '0X' WHEN (([Project1].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL)) THEN '0X0X' WHEN (([Project3].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project3].[C1] IS NOT NULL)) THEN '0X1X' ELSE '0X2X' END AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
CASE WHEN (( NOT (([Project1].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (([Project3].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project3].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (([Project2].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project2].[C1] IS NOT NULL)))) THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN (([Project1].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL)) THEN [Project1].[HasCycleCar] WHEN (([Project3].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project3].[C1] IS NOT NULL)) THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) END AS [C2], 
CASE WHEN (( NOT (([Project1].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (([Project3].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project3].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (([Project2].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project2].[C1] IS NOT NULL)))) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN (([Project1].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL)) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN (([Project3].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project3].[C1] IS NOT NULL)) THEN [Project3].[Seats] END AS [C3], 
CASE WHEN (( NOT (([Project1].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (([Project3].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project3].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (([Project2].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project2].[C1] IS NOT NULL)))) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN (([Project1].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL)) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN (([Project3].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project3].[C1] IS NOT NULL)) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE [Project2].[Capacity] END AS [C4]
FROM    [dbo].[Vehicles] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent2].[HasCycleCar] AS [HasCycleCar], 
    cast(1 as bit) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Motorcycles] AS [Extent2] ) AS [Project1] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Project1].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
    [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent3].[Capacity] AS [Capacity], 
    cast(1 as bit) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Trucks] AS [Extent3] ) AS [Project2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Project2].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
    [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent4].[Seats] AS [Seats], 
    cast(1 as bit) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[PassengerCars] AS [Extent4] ) AS [Project3] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Project3].[Id]
WHERE [Extent1].[CreatedAt] >= (DATEADD (day, -10, SysUtcDateTime()))
```

Comes I need only base information, but EF reads all, more that with cumbersome query. I understand that EF needs to comply with polymorphic behavior and return an object of the type which it was created.

But how can I simpfly my that he did not read unnecassary?

Comment: You are getting a list of Vehicle records, are you not ? If so, what is the problem with that ? Is this not what the code you wrote is supposed to do ? What you pasted at the end is simply EF's translation into sql, so it can translate c# linq syntax into Database-readable sql (a RDBMS does not know how to interpret c#'s linq)

Comment: Yeah but as you can see it reads all over the information for each vehicle

Comment: What do you mean with "all over" ? The joins probably translate the virtual collections you defined in the Vechile class (and its nested ones). How do you expect it to be ?

Comment: Look like you have some kind of hierarchy but as collections. Did you disabled Lazy loading?

Comment: Its done unnessacary work for me when check all columns, which not needed in this query. Its take some time, how can I avoid this?

Comment: If you add your entity configurations could help us to understand what you have there and find the correct behavior. EF behaves in different ways it applies a Convention over configuration concept for robust designs needs helps with some extra configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want a subset of the properties of the entity types you can include a projection in the query (either to an anonymous or named type):

```
var results = from v in context.Vehicles
              …
              select new VechicleSubSet {
                Id = v.Id,
                Name = v.Name
              };
```

When `results` is enumerated (triggering the query to the database) only `Name` and `Id` will be selected (other columns might be referenced if used elsewhere in the query).

Note: in your SQL it looks like you have configured something like `Table per Class` in your object-table mapping: hence EF is trying to return all the data within that mapping, not just from a single table.

Comment: It seems to be true, I`ll check it for performance and accept your answer. Thanks.